# SublimeText 3 Autocomplete not working on MacOS

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

Autocomplete isn't triggered when I type < or <[character] in html file or just normal typing. It happens on MacOS. I reset Sublime and leave all default, removed ~/.codeintel as well. In Window, everything is still good.

This is my setting

```
{
    "fade_fold_buttons": false,
    "highlight_line": true,
}
```

This is video recorded when I'm typing
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AB0DBBF4EF6E0186!90449&authkey=!AOiPc-pkbBu76UU&ithint=file%2cswf

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried putting `"auto_complete": true` in your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file?

Comment: Yes, I tried and still nothing so far :(

Comment: Try adding `"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"` to your `Preferences.sublime-settings` (I'm grasping at straws now though).

Comment: Thank you for patience with me, but still nothing

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your user preference settings? Also, if you could add a screenshot of the editor when you're trying to type a tag, that would be helpful.

Comment: @saadg: edited with bonus video :)

Comment: Has anybody faced this problem?